# Appropriate AngularJS1.X espression for specific JSON

Tags: angularjs, json

Is posibble in AngularJS1.X by using `ng-repeat` directive, for JSON named `weeks_and_days`:

```
`[{
    "week_nr": "1",
    "day_nr": "1,2,3,4,5,6,7"
}, {
    "week_nr": "2",
    "day_nr": "8,9,10,11,12,13,14"
}, {
    "week_nr": "3",
    "day_nr": "15,16,17,18,19,20,21"
}, {
    "week_nr": "4",
    "day_nr": "22,23,24,25,26,27,28"
}, {
    "week_nr": "5",
    "day_nr": "29,30,31"
}]`
```

to get **each and every** `day_nr`, so for example, for `week_nr`: `1` I would **sepearte** results as: "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" ?

If it is possible how should the AngularJS {{expression}} look in this case? If it's not possible, how would have to be this JSON constructed to achive my goal?

For the request in comment I'm attaching the html files, **index.html**:

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> Calendar </title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Include the core AngularJS library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include the AngularJS routing library -->
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular-route.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="CalendarApp">
    <div ng-view>


    </div>
    <!-- Modules -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="js/controllers/DaysController.js"></script>

    <!-- Services -->
    <script src="js/services/days.js"></script>
</body>

</html>`
```

and the view **test.html**:

```
`<div ng-repeat="week in weeks_and_days"> 
<p> {{week}} </p>
</div> `
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
$scope.weeks_and_days = [{
    "week_nr": "1",
    "day_nr": "1,2,3,4,5,6,7"
}, {
    "week_nr": "2",
    "day_nr": "8,9,10,11,12,13,14"
}, {
    "week_nr": "3",
    "day_nr": "15,16,17,18,19,20,21"
}, {
    "week_nr": "4",
    "day_nr": "22,23,24,25,26,27,28"
}, {
    "week_nr": "5",
    "day_nr": "29,30,31"
}]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
<div ng-repeat="week in weeks_and_days">
<p>Week : {{week.week_nr}}</p> <p>Days : {{week.day_nr}}</p>
<div>
</body>
```

Comment: That is a good example. However, I am using RESTful API, and I want to get the JSON, which was generated from MySQL querries.

Comment: Whatever this is same for all, based on JSON or object structure.  Some time you need to use track by, Sometime multiple ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help.Please add the necessory style. Always consider grouping multiple data as arrays, and pass numbers as numbers itself, It will increase the performance. Thanks @Manikandan for the reference code. Thank you.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
$scope.weeks_and_days = [{
    "week_nr": 1,
    "day_nr": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
}, {
    "week_nr": 2,
    "day_nr": [8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
}, {
    "week_nr": 3,
    "day_nr": [15,16,17,18,19,20,21]
}, {
    "week_nr": 4,
    "day_nr": [22,23,24,25,26,27,28]
}, {
    "week_nr": 5,
    "day_nr": [29,30,31]
}]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
<table>
<tr><th>Week</th><th>Day</th></tr>
<tr ng-repeat="week in weeks_and_days"><td>{{week.week_nr}}</td><td ng-repeat="day in week.day_nr">{{day}}&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your JSON is in your scope. Can't you use an ng-repeat to repeat through your weeks_and_days like:

```
ng-repeat="week in weeks_and_days"
```

Then use the following expressions to display them:

```
{{week.week_nr}}
{{week.day_nr}}
```

Comment: This is exactly how I'm trying to do so. In reference to your example, it works, when I do `{{week}}`, I get the whole JSON, but when I want to do `{{week.week_nr}}
{{week.day_nr}}` - the browser displayes empty screen.

Comment: I just read your comment on Manikandan's answer. Could you display your current HTML code in your question?

Comment: @Rico11112016 The way you wrote your ng-repeat looks fine to me. Yet week.week_nr and week.day_nr display absolutely no values?

Comment: Yes, I had the same effect - no values for `week.week_nr` and `week.day_nr`.